# Как делать запросы с HTTPS на HTTP

Tags: http, https, xmlhttprequest, xhr

Мне нужно делать запросы с фронтенда, который работает на 443 порту (на HTTPS) на бекенд, который работает на другом порту на HTTP. Т.к. 443 порт занят, запросы нужно отсылать без безопасного подключения. Браузер выводит ошибки, что нельзя делать запросы с HTTPS на HTTP, а только на HTTPS.

Добавлял этот тег в HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">`

Но он просто в адресе запроса http:// заменяет на https://, а бекэнд не может принимать HTTPS-запросы

Подскажите, можно ли каким-то образом отсылать запросы с HTTPS ИМЕННО на HTTP?

Comment: Не нужно. Нужно настроить https на беке.